# Ray Cummings story about a Mercurian with frog legs

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story (before 1925) from Ray Cummings in which he described a bearded Mercurian with frog legs. Does someone know which story this is?

Comment: I have a lot of Cummings' books (though not all) and the nearest I can find is in _Aerita of the Light Country_ where there are bearded Mercurians (he calls them _Mercutians_) but they are human in appearance and don't have legs like frogs.

Comment: thank you very much, but this story (Aerita of the Light Country) was published in 1941, too late (the description of the Mercurians i'm looking for was set in a french periodical for youth (Le petit inventeur, #41, april 14th, 1925). Perhaps the original story from Cummings was published in a popularisation of science magazine

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's *Tama, Princess of Mercury*? It is a Ray Cummings story about Mercury. Something mentioned is that all the women of Mercury have wings, but haven't been able to find anything about someone with frog legs.

[image]

> Guy Palisse, space-explorer, returned to Earth in the Bolton Flying Cube after ten years on the Sun's first planet, Mercury. He returned to report that he had warded off war between the two worlds, and to wed before an admiring planet his beautiful fiancee, Tama, winged princess of Mercury's Light Country.

> But following on Palisse's orbit was a new wave of terror, as barbarian hordes from Mercury's Cold Country descended to launch their conquest of Earth. And Palisse's triumph turned to near disaster as the frenzied Mercurians plotted to kidnap Tama and bring the Earth to ruin.

Comment: I have the book and there is no mention of frogs in it at all, legs or otherwise.

Comment: thank you, but effectivelly Tama is not the book i'm looking for, and it was published after 1925